# How to draw a cube using triangle_strip in android

Tags: android

I'm stucked with triangle strip. I know what is triangle strip but I'm facing problem while drawing a cube. Can anybody tell me how to draw a cube using triangle_strip of 16 vertices in opengl android.

Comment: I don't have mathematical proof, but I am quite sure it is impossible to draw a cube with `TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Use `TRIANGLES` instead

Comment: If I use TRIANGLE_STRIP there is no need of indices array that's why i am looking for this.Please share url if you have any regarding building a cube.

Comment: You can use `TRIANGLES` without indices as well if you want to. You can take a look at the api-demos, especially `Cube.java` and `CubeRenderer.java` to see how to create a cube with indices.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/index.html

Comment: But in cube.java, there you can see indices[] array. And I want to rid of indices array as in TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Comment: Here may be the answer for what you was interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157998/cube-with-triangle-strips-and-vector-normals-in-opengl

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032334/how-many-vertices-needed-in-to-draw-a-cube-in-opengl-es
or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157998/cube-with-triangle-strips-and-vector-normals-in-opengl
they use 14 indtead of 16.